# apache nutch file download after button clicking

Tags: nutch

Is it possible for apache nutch to download a file from a url after button clicking and index it?

Example - Suppose the url is http://example.com
File is downloaded after clicking a button on http://example.com and getting saved. How can we do it in apache nutch.

Answer (score 2):

This really deppends on how the button is implementend, if the download action is just a link to the direct file it should work fine. If the download action happens through some javascript event or in a form with a `<button>` element then Nutch would not detect this. Perhaps using the `protocol-selenium` could help if the link is generated using some javascript.

**EDIT**

Since the button is triggered on something like the onclick event, then your best bet is to use `protocol-interactiveselenium` (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/protocol-interactiveselenium/README.md) and perhaps implement a custom handler if you need to. I haven't tested this personally but should work.

Comment: Thanks Jorge :) , hyperlink for downloading file is attached to button by javascript after page is loaded, thats why facing this issue. I have tried using selenium plugin in nutch-default.xml , but no luck :(